# Trying to access debian/scripts and debian/rules

Tags: kernel, scripts, chmod

I am trying to rebuild the kernel because I want to change jiffies to 1ms.

I'm following a [turorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)  and it is stated that I shall do `chmod a+x debian/scripts/*` but I can not find the debian folder nor the scripts folder. Where can I find this?

Comment: did you perform the `Build Environment Step`?

Comment: Yes I did. I did it in the terminal in ubuntu. It feels strange that I do this while I'm in the system but I assume this is where I do it.

Comment: First of all, where did you get the kernel source? If it is mainline, it is not debianized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cloned sources from Ubuntu git or using a deb source package, then debian directory is at the second level. Like that

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
cd ubuntu-precise
```

And you will see "debian" in ls.
But actually you do not need to set +x. It must be already there.
Just do

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

and it will build.